# как загрузить фото на стену в FB при клике на фото на своем сайте?

Tags: javascript, php, html5

посоветовали эту библиотеку 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/uploadphoto

установил я my-server:my-php-project$ composer require facebook/graph-sdk

ДОПУСТИМ ПОЛУЧУ Я ПРИ КЛИКЕ ссылку на картинку с помощью js а дальше как ? куда этот код https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/uploadphoto php вставлять ? спасибо.

с самого начала если можно что то еще нужно подключать кроме facebook/graph-sdk ?